# Why my React app is not loading correctly (broken) in localhost?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I had my react project working correctly in localhost. Then, I decided to deploy it to github pages and it worked perfectly on the server too. Now, I'm trying to work on it again on localhost but it is not showing correctly. For some reason, photos are not loading and some css is not working correctly and after compile it in PowerShell says this:

---

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view myportfolio in the browser.

Local: http://localhost:3000/myportfolio

On Your Network: http://192.168.56.1:3000/myportfolio

Note that the development build is not optimized.

To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

---

So if I go to my GitHub pages it is loading correctly but not in localhost (running npm start).

Any suggestion? Thank you in advance and let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: What does your console say? are there any errors such as `can not load resources`

Comment: @RahulDwivedi No errors at all. It is still working fine on github pages but in localhost my css is messed up.

Comment: Do you get any errors on `console` on your local machine? Can you share the guthub link?

Comment: @RahulDwivedi I'm a React beginner so from what I know I don't see any errors in console neither. Sure the project github link: https://github.com/diegosimonelli/myportfolio

Comment: Is it deployed on github pages?

Comment: @RahulDwivedi Yes, it is on diegosimonelli.github.io/myportfolio/

Comment: I did clone the project and there are various problems in that. You seem to have used `jquery` and third party js libraries directly without installing from npm. Another problem is you can directly give the path of images in your project like this `./img` you should use a variable and use curly braces {}. Antother thing is you must provide `key` whenever you're mapping a list .

Comment: @RahulDwivedi Thank you. I'll try to fix those problems. But why they are working fine on github pages and giving errors in localhost?

Comment: The reason for that is correct path are not found on local. For e.g if you use `%PUBLIC_URL%` before each src in your script the errors will be gone. Similarly if you correct the path of the image, you should be ale to see the image. The reason why it's working on `gh-pages` is because it builds static files before the deployment in which the relative paths are are correctly refrenced

Comment: There are some other problems too. Let me summarise them in an answer

Comment: @RahulDwivedi I just fixed my problems with the scripts with your suggestion. Thank you so much. I'm just having trouble trying to figure out the right format for the path of the image. How to add curly braces {} to it?

Comment: Checkout the answer below

Answer (score 2):

I did clone your repositories and found these problems:

1. You have been directly imported many third-party js given their relative path in the index.html. That doesn't work. You should append `%PUBLIC_URL%` before them. For e.g.

   `<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>` and similary for other script files.
2. But even this is not the best that you can do. You must not try to use jquery or third party js in a React App. Also, make it a part to install the related JS though `npm` and make them a part of the package.
3. You'll have to use `<img src={require('/public/images/background.png')}...` (Btw, the image name on your `gh-pages` is different. It's `logo.png` there)if you want the `webpack` to compile and make it a part of your project. Also, the path must reside within `src` and not `public` folder.
4. Other errors are are related to `keys`. Whenever you're mapping and iterating through a list in react you must specify a unique key.

Comment: Thank you for all the help! I really appreciate it!